# Use Foreach to iterate over 2d array: Cannot convert string to string[]

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to iterate over a 2d string array but my foreach statement has a compile error that I dont understand.

**What am I doing wrong in this simple example & how can I perform what I am trying to do?**

```
string URL = PRODUCT_URL + "?";

string[,] a = {{"a","1"},{"b","2"}};
foreach (string[] param in a)    // error cannot convert type string to string[]
{
    URL += param[0] + "=" + param[1] + "&";
}
```

Comment: wouldn't a dictionary be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has two similar constructs, Arrays of arrays and multidimensional arrays. What you have here is a 2 dimensional array, so the loop you want is

```
foreach (string param in a)
{
...
}
```

If you wanted to go the array of arrays approach, you'd want:

```
string[][] a = {new[] {"a","1"}, new[] {"b","2"}}
```

for your declaration. 
Internally, C# implements the multidimensional array as a normal array with a size equal to the product of the dimension (e.g. since your `a` is 2x2, it would be a linear array of length 4). This way, the programmer can use a more convenient syntax for member access and initialization.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-dimensional array of string is not the same as an array of arrays of string.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-D Array string[,] is not the same as string[][] (like C/C++), despite the initialization.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code like this:

```
string URL = PRODUCT_URL + "?";

string[][] a = { new[] { "a", "1" }, new[] { "b", "2" } };
foreach (string[] param in a)    // error cannot convert type string to string[]
{
    URL += param[0] + "=" + param[1] + "&";
}
```

With your code you are iterating a,1,b,2 (4 loops).